# Android hangs after rebooting when upgrading to 2.3.5

Tags: updates, htc-wildfire

I used HTC's update software functionality to upgrade my Android to version 2.3.5. Though, upon reboot all I get is the cryptic icon (a phone and a red triagle with an exclamation mark inside). When entering System Recovery (volume + power button) I see:

```
Copying fotaBoot to /data/system for customize reload...
Verify current system...
  assert failed: apply_patch_check("/system/framework/com.htc.resources.apk", ..., ...)
  E:Error in /sdcard/download/OTA_Marvel_S_HTC_Europe_2.13.401.3-1.33.401.3_release_237845pg2016qpaadczbkc.zip
  (Status 7)
  Installation aborted.
```

And four options are given to me:

- Reboot system now (which I have done)
- Apply update from sdcard
- Wipe data/factory reset
- Wipe cache partition

I am tempted to select "Apply update from sdcard". Though, I cannot imply if I will find sideffects in doing so as I do not understand the meaning of "Status 7".

Any help would be appreciated!